# Angular subscription to boolean

Tags: angular

I have a service as follow:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    }

    get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        let token = this.token;
        if (!!token) {
            let jwt = new JwtHelperService();
            try {
                if (jwt.isTokenExpired(token)) {
                    let refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
                    if (!!refreshToken) {
                        // I need this to be boolean
                        return this.refreshToken(refreshToken);
                    }
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                this.logout();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // I expect this method to return a boolean value
    refreshToken(refreshToken: string) {
        return this.api.post<JwtToken>('/auth/refresh', { refreshToken: refreshToken })
            .subscribe(user => {
                if (user && user.access_token) {
                    localStorage.setItem('access_token', user.access_token);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

by this code I get authentication status by `isAuthenticated` method.
I need this method to return as `boolean`.

my problem is that `refreshToken` method returns subscription and I need it as boolean.
I can convert `isAuthenticated` method to `Observable<boolean>` but I also need to use this method in my HTML. that's why i want it as boolean.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have at least one async observable, the whole call chain should return observables, so in your isAuthenticated you need to return Observable<boolean>

Comment: I can write you an example how to do that

Comment: @AmirArbabian I get it. but how I use `isAuthenticated` in html. for example: `<div *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated"><a (click)="logoff()">logoff</a></div>`

Comment: You can use **async** pipe like `<div *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated | async"><a (click)="logoff()">logoff</a></div>`. It subscribes on your Observable and returns the result. + It automatically unsubscribes from it whenever that part of template is being destroyed, so you do not worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here it is:

```
get isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    let token = this.token;
    if (!!token) {
        let jwt = new JwtHelperService();
        try {
            if (jwt.isTokenExpired(token)) {
                let refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
                if (!!refreshToken) {
                    return this.refreshToken(refreshToken);
                }
                return Observable.of(false);
            } else {
                return Observable.of(true);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            this.logout();
            return Observable.of(false);
        }
    }
    return Observable.of(false);
}


 refreshToken(refreshToken: string) {
        return this.api.post<JwtToken>('/auth/refresh', { refreshToken: refreshToken })
            .map(user => user && user.access_token)
            .do(userHasAccessToken => userHasAccessToken && localStorage.setItem('access_token', user.access_token));
    }
```

There are no other ways to do that **without blocking your main js thread**, you either need to use **Observable/Promise** to asynchronously wait until your **http call** finishes.
Hope that helps.